# Laravel Mot de passe oublié ne marche pas

Tags: php, laravel, smtp

I am trying to use laravel to send emails but I have the following error:

> Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError Maximum execution time
> of 60 seconds exceeded.

I don't know if I need to do any other configuration apart from the .env for at least forgotten password to work
Here is my current config:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.hostinger.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=info@easybos.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=info@easybos.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=EasyBos
```

Comment: Did you check [Laravel's mail documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail)? There can be found configuration and other details.

Comment: Please make sure the entire post(including title) is in English.